# Can subClasses listen to superClass dispatched events?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, event-handling, flex4

onI've got some issues with listening to events in Flex4 (actionscript3).

In the code below, the event dispatched in method1 class A, isn't detected in method2 class C. I tryed using bubbles=true for the dispatched event but it didn't change anything.

Do you have any suggestoins?

```
Class A extends EventDispatcher{
    public function method1():void{
        dispatch(new Event("onEvent"));
    }
}

Class B extends A{
    ....
}

Class C extends B{
    public function method2():void{
        addEventListener("onEvent", onEventResult);

        method1();

        function onEventResult(event:Event):void{
            ...
        }
    }
}

Class D{
    function mainMethod():void{
        var c:C = new C();
        c.methode2();
    }
}
```

Comment: it should works, just fix the compile errors, e.g. listener name

Comment: There are no compiling errors. When I run the application in debug mode with Flash Builder, I arrive to the statement where the event is dispatched and then nothing happens, because I suppose the event isn't caught.

Comment: it works for me (your code) and should works by default, add _trace_ to be sure, may be some problems with debugger

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's not enough to say, in class C,: `addEventListener("onEvent", onEventResult);`

The only place your class A event can 'bubble up' to is the stage. So you must target the **stage** with your 'addEventListener' method.

Try `stage.addEventListener("onEvent", onEventResult);`

But of course, from your code, there's no evidence that an instance of any of these classes is actually *on* a stage. I'm assuming that you're just not showing that.

Comment: None of the classes is on a stage. So I suppose it's not going to work.

Comment: And are any of them instantiated? You have to actually USE the class in order to get its functions to work!